# Histogram charts with a lot of data

Tags: javascript, charts

I will have on my site about 25 boxes with histogram charts and each of them will show results from 150 seconds, each second - 2 or 3 data sources. Finally about: 10k elements. It will be refreshing in 10 seconds intervals. I am wondering which solution will be the best option for better performance:
1) Normal divs with dynamically changed height
2) Drawing some canvas 
3) Using SVG

I need some hint.

Comment: In our experience with JavaScript charting, rendering 25 charts on a page can lead to performance issues which are not necessarily related to the options you laid out. These can be due to browser memory constraints and/or garbage collection issues in JS. How long do you need to store this in browser memory? You might want to ask questions specifically to canvas and SVG experts.

Comment: It should be refreshed all the time when user have opened this page. User open page, check statistics ( usually fast - about 10 seconds, sometimes it can be longer like minutes ) and close page just after that.